# Meaning of "four into a ten stretch"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There's a Netflix series called "The Gentlemen". The following dialogue takes place in it.

> Man: "So I hear your dad's caught a nasty cold. How long's he got left?"
>
> Woman: "He's four into a ten stretch."
>
> Man:   "Ouch."

What does "four into a ten stretch" mean?

Comment: He's 4 years into a 10 year sentence.

Comment: Specifically, a *prison* sentence.

Comment: Although "do a stretch" could easily refer to yoga these days, in the U.S. more than, say, 20 years ago, it would almost certainly mean being in prison. You could usually rely on context to figure out which sense is intended, although if people are doing yoga in prison I don't know what you'd do.

Comment: The phrase, with the meaning explained by @KillingTime, is fairly common. What isn't is the previous line - "caught a cold" isn't common slang for being sent to prison. This misdirects the reader.

Comment: @ChrisH I haven't seen the show, but it sounds like they're talking in a kind of private code. It's not uncommon to make up euphemisms on the fly, if you expect the other person to understand from context.

Comment: @Barmar I've also only seen the quote here. Your interpretation seems likely; with context others might also be plausible. If that line causes confusion, it's dispelled by the line the OP asked about - but only for those familiar with the usage

Comment: @JonathanZ "stretch" has a number of meanings, but the only sense where "four into ten" makes sense is a prison sentence (or something being treated as a metaphoric sentence). It's hard to imagine how one could make this apply to yoga.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it incorporates both deletion (four years) and prison argot (a ten stretch), making it a better fit on Literature.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why would that make this off topic here?

Comment: @Laurel: The usage 'a ten stretch' constitutes the basis of a single question, clearly answered by a dictionary {eg [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stretch): **stretch**: a period of time that a criminal spends in prison:
• _Her brother's doing a ten-year stretch for armed robbery_.}

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of *stretch* according to [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6jqni2q):

> in prison/Und. uses [abbr. SE stretch of time].
>
> - a twelve-month sentence; thus *two stretch*, two years; *three stretch*, three years etc

Thus: four [years] into a ten [year] stretch [of prison time]

Comment: Isn't Green's Dictionary one of the favoured few now? It's certainly in the sensible list of 'common reference works' we used to use.

Answer (score -1):

Four years served out of a ten year prison sentence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).